# Python multiprocessing.Pool workers remain idle

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am a beginner with Python. I am trying to run a simple function using multiprocessing.Pool, but when I run the program, it does not get processed. I can see that distinct processes are spawned, but that they [remain idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp9dT.png). For example, the code below does does generate two worker processes but no output and nothing else:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x):
    print("Process "+str(x))
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)            
    result = pool.map(f, range(1000))
```

I am running Python 3.9 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. OS is Windows 10. I encountered the same problem using Python 3.7 on this computer. I have tried the same code on another computer (Also Windows 10, VS2019) and it works fine. The difference is that this one has an [i9 Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGAGo.png), while the other has an i7.

I have searched online, but I have not encountered any similar issue or any fix for my problem. Does anyone have any idea why does this happen and/or possible fixes? May the type of processor have something to do with it? Thanks!

Comment: Please use tag `visual-studio` if, and only if your problem is directly related to Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a just a guess:

I know that this will not run under Jupyter Notebook or the interactive interpreter. See the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html), in particular the section:

[image]

The solution for those environments is to take your worker function, `f`, and place it in a separate module, for example *worker.py*, and to import the worker function:

```py
import multiprocessing
from worker import f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    result = pool.map(f, range(1000))
```

Give this a shot and let us know for others who also have Visual Studio whether this worked or not. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Booboo for your answer! I tried your solution but it did not work. Instead, I took a more radical approach and decided to reinstall python along with all of the other packages. Surprisingly, it worked! Therefore, and embarrassingly, it is highly probable that the problem was related with some missing dependencies that I overlooked on the first installation (although I cannot exactly pinpoint wat was missing after the fact). Case closed! Sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Then why are you accepting my answer? You should un-accept it.